# Android, вопрос про mipmap

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Добрый день, возник вопрос: стоит ли каждые изображения закидывать в mipmap?

Допустим есть логотип, я его сделал из 5 форматов разных размеров и раскидал по папкам? Нужно ли это делать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> стоит ли каждые изображения закидывать в mipmap

Каждые – не стоит, но, например, иконку приложения следует размещать именно там.

В `mipmap` следует хранить изображения, которые на устройстве, в зависимости от того, где они отображаются, будут иметь разные размеры. Формулировка, конечно, звучит не очень, но далее постараюсь разъяснить суть.

### Разница между `drawable` и `mipmap`

Разница между `drawable` и `mipmap` заключается в том, что изображения, находящиеся в каталоге `drawable` для некоторых DPI могут быть исключены из приложения на этапе его сборки, а изображения из `mipmap` – не могут.

### Зачем нужен `mipmap`?

Для корректного отображения изображений на дисплеях с различными DPI в Android были введены квалификаторы (например, mdpi, hdpi). Чтобы изображения корректно выглядели на всех устройствах, необходимо разместить эти изображения со всеми доступными квалификаторами (в соответствующих разрешениях).

Размещение изображений в различных разрешениях влечет за собой увеличение размера приложения.

Допустим, Вы знаете, что у Боба такое-то значение DPI, а у Алисы – некоторое другое. Чтобы уменьшить размер приложения, Вы можете отдельно собрать приложение для Боба и отдельно для Алисы, включая изображения только в необходимом разрешении. При сборке проекта Вы можете исключить ненужные изображения (с помощью соответствующей конфигурации Gradle), например:

```
exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
```

Вроде бы все хорошо: исключены ненужные изображения и размер приложения уменьшен. Однако не все так гладко. Некоторые изображения могут быть отображены в разрешениях, которые не соответствуют тому, в котором Вы оставили эти изображения в проекте. Пример – иконка приложения, в некоторых лаунчерах она может быть увеличена. Так как иконка приложения у Вас в единственном разрешении (как и все другие изображения), то она будет увеличена и произойдет т.н. *пикселизация* – изображение будут размыто (при большом апскейле будут заметны квадратики).

Вот тут-то и приходит на помощь `mipmap` – изображения, размещенные там, не будут исключены. То есть если Вы укажите в Gradle:

```
exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
```

то соответствующие изображения из `drawable` будут исключены, а из `mipmap` – нет.

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ

Answer (score 4):

Конечно нужно. Каталоги mipmap предназначены для иконок приложения, все остальные изображения должны быть помещены drawable.

Иконки, как и другие изображения, создаются разных размеров для того, чтобы не терялось качество при масштабировании. Ланчеру в некоторых случаях нужны более крупные иконки, и отдельный каталог для иконок позволяет избежать дополнительного преобразования.

Подробнее здесь: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Вообще о том, как устроены ресурсы, и как Андроид находит наиболее подходящий, есть здесь (доступно на русском): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ