# Удаление drawable-ресурсов

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

Когда происходит удаление drawable-ресурсов (when packaging an APK - при сборке APK или при установке APK на конкретное устройство?) и почему mipmap-ресурсы при этом не удаляются?

> while drawable resources might be removed when packaging an APK, such
>   as for the Gradle for Android split system for making density-specific
>   editions of an app, mipmap resources are left alone, apparently

**P.S.**
И что значит "Android split system"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Когда происходит удаление drawable-ресурсов (when packaging an APK - при сборке APK или при установке APK на конкретное устройство?)

Удаление ресурсов происходит на этапе сборки проекта (ведь цель этого – уменьшить размер APK). Исключить ресурсы можно с помощью оператора `exclude`, например:

```
exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
```

> и почему mipmap-ресурсы при этом не удаляются?

В этом и есть вся *фишка* `mipmap`-ресурсов. Далее процитирую [свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620810/220996):

> ### Зачем нужен `mipmap`?
>
> Для корректного отображения изображений на дисплеях с различными DPI в Android были введены квалификаторы (например, mdpi, hdpi). Чтобы изображения корректно выглядели на всех устройствах, необходимо разместить эти изображения со всеми доступными квалификаторами (в соответствующих разрешениях).
>
> Размещение изображений в различных разрешениях влечет за собой увеличение размера приложения.
>
> Допустим, Вы знаете, что у Боба такое-то значение DPI, а у Алисы – некоторое другое. Чтобы уменьшить размер приложения, Вы можете отдельно собрать приложение для Боба и отдельно для Алисы, включая изображения только в необходимом разрешении. При сборке проекта Вы можете исключить ненужные изображения (с помощью соответствующей конфигурации Gradle), например:
>
> ```
> exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
> ```
>
> Вроде бы все хорошо: исключены ненужные изображения и размер приложения уменьшен. Однако не все так гладко. Некоторые изображения могут быть отображены в разрешениях, которые не соответствуют тому, в котором Вы оставили эти изображения в проекте. Пример – иконка приложения, в некоторых лаунчерах она может быть увеличена. Так как иконка приложения у Вас в единственном разрешении (как и все другие изображения), то она будет увеличена и произойдет т.н. *пикселизация* – изображение будут размыто (при большом апскейле будут заметны квадратики).
>
> Вот тут-то и приходит на помощь `mipmap` – изображения, размещенные там, не будут исключены. То есть если Вы укажите в Gradle:
>
> ```
> exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
> ```
>
> то соответствующие изображения из `drawable` будут исключены, а из `mipmap` – нет.

---

Android split system – условное название [совокупности конструкций](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html), которые используется для разделения ресурсов для APK.

Comment: То есть, удаление drawable-ресурсов происходит только при явном указании `exclude` при сборке?

Comment: @Ksenia, Точно сказать не могу, но судя по [этому](https://dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager) – в процессе установки удаление ресурсов не происходит. Хотя могу ошибаться.